# Play sound only when Ring/Silent switch is on ring

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm working on an app with a piano keyboard. I want that the sound after key-pressing is only played, when "Ring/Silent" switch is on ring. Then it should stop background music from other apps . If the "Ring/Silent" switch is on silent, it shouldn't do anything and let the background music from other apps play (like Spotify).

What I tried (with Spotify as background music):

**Option 1 [AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient]:**

- "Ring/Silent" switch is on ring: background music doesn't stop and it plays in-app sound together with background music (-> What I don't want)
- "Ring/Silent" switch is on silent: background music doesn't stop and no in-app sounds are played (-> What I want)

**Option 2 [AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient]:**

- "Ring/Silent" switch is on ring: background music stops and it plays in-app sound (-> What I want)
- "Ring/Silent" switch is on silent: background music stops, but no in-app sounds are played (-> What I want, it shouldn't stop background music)

I think that Option 2 is the closest option I can get. The iPhone shouldn't stop background music when "Ring/Silent" switch is on silent and I'd be happy.

**Option 3 [AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback]:**

- "Ring/Silent" switch is on ring: background music stops and it plays in-app sound (-> What I want)
- "Ring/Silent" switch is on silent: background music stops and it plays in-app sound (-> What I don't want)

**My Code:**

```
let NoteSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentNote.sound, ofType: "m4a")!)
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NoteSound as URL)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
} catch {
    print("Problem in getting File")
}
```

In the code example I only changed `.setCategory()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native API to check if the phone is on *Silent* or not, and you are discouraged from basing your app's functionality on such user choices (On low battery mode, Charging or not, ...).

There is a hack to check whether the device is muted or not: Play a short sound of 0.5s minimum duration, and detect the time it took to play. For more details on this workaround, have a look [here](https://github.com/akramhussein/Mute).

Comment: I'm surprised there is no official API, since Apple mentions that apps should behave accordingly if the phone is in silent mode and only essential (e.g. by the user initiated) noises should be played back. Such as audio during media playback, alarms, etc: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/audio/ – and I also came across the playback workaround, but it's a little hacky. Nice pod though!

Comment: I presume it would stop the background music though - I guess I’ll just work with AVAudioSessionAmbient. So if the user is annoyed by in-app sounds he can just mute his device, but background music will never stop.